# How to create a function in sql server for finding if data exists or not?

Tags: sql-server, function

Need to know the syntax for creating function and the difference between inline table value function and multi statement tabled value function.

Comment: You can Google that, plenty of data available.

Comment: but don't know which function to use scalar or table value

Comment: Scalar Function return single parameter, table valued function return table like multi parameter values. If you simply want to check data existense, Scalar Function is enough. Note that Using Scalar Function is performance degrading issue in sql queries, you can use IF EXISTS clause instead.

Answer (score 4):

**SCALAR FUNCTION**
returns only a scalar/single value. We can use Scalar function in SELECT statement, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING clause. We have to mention data type of that single data value in RETURNS clause of the function definition.

E.g. Below function taking a date as input in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format and returning day and month from it. This is not mandatory that function always take an input parameter but it must always return a value.

```
create function GetDateDaynMonth(@date varchar(20))
returns varchar(20)
as
begin
    declare @DaynMonth varchar (20)
SELECT @DaynMonth = FORMAT (convert(datetime, @date, 103), 'dd MMMM') 
return @DaynMonth;
end
go
```

**  - To execute Function **

```
select dbo.GetDateDaynMonth('25/06/2018')
```

**TABLE VALUED FUNCTION**
A table-valued user defined function returns a result set/row set instead of a single/scalar value. It can be invoked in FROM or JOIN clause of a SELECT query.

***For more details with multiple examples***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

**INLINE TABLE VALUED FUNCTION**

An inline table valued function definition specifies only RETURNS TABLE and not the table definition. The entire query batch or code or select query inside the function is a single RETURN statement

```
CREATE FUNCTION CustomerProductDetails (@CustomerID NCHAR(5))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
        -- Select statement
        )
GO
```

**MULTI STATEMENT TABLE VALUED FUNCTION**

Multi-statement table valued function definition specifies RETURNS along with the definition of TABLE VARIABLE. The function body might consists of multiple statements and one of which will populate this TABLE VARIABLE. And the scope/life of this TABLE VARIABLE is limited to only this function - outside of this function it is not available.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CustomerOrderDetails (@CustomerID NCHAR(5))
RETURNS @CustomerOrders TABLE (
    CustomerID NCHAR(5)
    ,CompanyName NVARCHAR(40)
    ,OrderID INT
    ,OrderDate DATETIME
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @CustomerOrders
    SELECT C.CustomerID
        ,C.CompanyName
        ,O.OrderID
        ,O.OrderDate
    FROM Customers C
    INNER JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
    WHERE C.CustomerID = @CustomerID

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the info...!!